Isolate container div from website's styles without iframe
I have a simple textarea and a preview modal, which shows me how the content of the textarea looks in an email (so it basically loads and shows the content as HTML).
Now, this preview is affected by my website's styles, and I want to isolate it so that it's as plain and exact as it would show when sent as an email. I don't want to use an iframe as it's not responsive. Are there better ways to do it?
I'm using VueJS, but ideally, I would like a solution that doesn't require installing a plugin just for this. The solution I'm looking for is either in CSS, vanilla JavaScript, or built-in Vue functionality.

You can isolate an element using scoped attribute within the <style> tag:
<style scoped>
.email-preview {
  all: initial;
}
</style>

with "initial" you reset the CSS property.

I believe this has been deprecated: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552. Unless you have documentation to show otherwise?

@mykaf this is a feature of Vue SFCs, not the same as the HTML standard.  I've added a link to the answer so this is more clear.

A non-VueJS answer
You can restrict the scope of stylesheet rules by enclosing them in a @scope at-rule. (There seems to be no equivalent attribute if they are loaded via a <link rel="stylesheet"> element.)


var style = mydiv.computedStyleMap()
console.log(
  "border-color",
  style.get("border-color").toString(),
  "background-color",
  style.get("background-color").toString(),
  "font-weight",
  style.get("font-weight").toString());
@scope (:root) to (#mydiv) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  div {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
}
<div>Subject to CSS</div>
<div id="mydiv">Exempt from CSS</div>
<iframe src="https://httpbin.org/html"></iframe>



<div id="mydiv"> is out of scope for the CSS rules, therefore it has no red border.
Likewise, the background-color in <div id="mydiv"> is transparent (rgba(0,0,0,0), not green as for the other <div>), but this means that the yellow body background shines through.
By contrast, the font-weight in both <div>s is bold (700) because it is inherited from the body.
"Shining through" and "inheritance" are two ways in which CSS rules affect elements beyond their scope. In other words: Restricting the scope of CSS rules is different from restricting their effect.
The answer to your question therefore depends on what you mean by "isolate". If you compare the solution to iframes, the message is mixed:

"Shining through" (of the background) affects <div id="mydiv"> as well as iframes.
"Inheritance" (of font weight) affects <div id="mydiv"> but not iframes.

